# GitHub API file query sometimes does not returns any file

Tags: github

I'm trying to fetch files in a given Github repo, and it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

### Examples

Works - response with some files:

- https://api.github.com/search/code?accept=application/vnd.github.v3+json&q=repo:amethysts-studio/coalescence (repo: https://github.com/amethysts-studio/coalescence)
- https://api.github.com/search/code?accept=application/vnd.github.v3+json&q=repo:DeadSuperHero/rms-dating-simulator (repo: https://github.com/DeadSuperHero/rms-dating-simulator)

Doesn't - empty response:

- https://api.github.com/search/code?accept=application/vnd.github.v3+json&q=repo:shishirsharma/cxosaga (repo: https://github.com/shishirsharma/cxosaga)
- https://api.github.com/search/code?accept=application/vnd.github.v3+json&q=repo:Kpielli/Val (repo: https://github.com/Kpielli/Val)

Why ? I want to have the files in both cases, how can I do that ? Note that I'll add a field `extension:rpy` to search for the .rpy files in the end, so I'm not sure asking for files another way might be ok with what I want to do.